# odd behavior in tkinter.tk.Sizegrip

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to learn tkinter in Python 3 so I'm not sure if I'm looking at a bug or I'm not doing things correctly.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
grip = ttk.Sizegrip(root).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(S,E))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

When the Sizegrip is grabbed the whole window moves rapidly (faster than my mouse pointer is moving) to the bottom of the screen. The window is being appropriately resized but the movement of the whole window is not what I would expect. [I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 with Python 3.1.2]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on my system (Ubuntu 10.10, Python 2.6) and I think it has to do with the window manager and not Tkinter. When I use Openbox, I don't have the problem, and when I use root.overrideredirect(1), I don't have the problem either.

What you can do is make a ttk.Label themed to look like a sizegrip. Bind it to  and resize the window accordingly. Here's a window with a sizegrip made this way:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#
# Callbacks:
#
# Change "bottom_right_corner" to "size_nw_se" and
# "arrow" to "left_ptr" if running on Windows.
#

def button_press(event):
    sizegrip["cursor"] = "bottom_right_corner"

def resize(event):
    deltax = event.x_root - root.winfo_rootx()
    deltay = event.y_root - root.winfo_rooty()
    if deltax < 1:
        deltax = 1
    if deltay < 1:
        deltay = 1
    root.geometry("%sx%s" % (deltax, deltay))

def button_release(event):
    sizegrip["cursor"] = "arrow"

# Widget Creation
root = Tk()                    
sizegrip = ttk.Label(root, style="Sizer.TLabel")

# Styling
style = ttk.Style()
style.layout("Sizer.TLabel", [("Sizegrip.sizegrip",
                               {"side": "bottom", "sticky": "se"})])

# Geometry Management
sizegrip.pack(side="bottom", anchor="se")

# Bindings
sizegrip.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", button_press)
sizegrip.bind("<B1-Motion>", resize)
sizegrip.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", button_release)

root.mainloop()
```

I am used to Python 2, so sorry if I've messed up a bit on the syntax. I tested it with Python 2 imports ("from Tkinter import *", and "import ttk") and it works. Let's just hope the imports are all that's different in Python 3.